# trigger firing another trigger not working

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have four table and two triggers.

```
Table A     tirggerA  , when before delete === > insert deleted data into Tabele AAAAA
Table B     tirggerB  , when before delete === > insert deleted data into Tabele BBBBB
```

the problem is triggerB works well when delete some data in Table B.

I want something like when deleting data from TableA,

1. deleted data of Table A inserted into Table AAAAA
2. deleted data of Table B (related with Table A data) also inserted into Table BBBBB.

I use cascade Delete on Table B and Table A relationship.

The problem is TriggerB never seems to fire when some data is deleted in TableA. Actually it should works because I have Cascade Delete relationship between those tables.  Any ideas?

Comment: hi everyone..

I just don't use cascade DELETE between two tables and just put DELETE command of TABLE B in tirggerA. works well now.
thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to just put the `delete` command in the trigger for table A.

Also you need to put the code in the `after delete` trigger, in the before delete, the delete has not happened yet and might be reversed.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ad_tableA_each AFTER DELETE ON tableA FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tableAAAA (f1,f2,f3) VALUES (old.f1, old.f2, old.f3);
  DELETE FROM tableB b WHERE b.a_id = old.id; /*use this instead of foreign key*/
END $$

CREATE TRIGGER ad_tableB_each AFTER DELETE ON tableB FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tableBBBB (f1,f2,f3) VALUES (old.f1, old.f2, old.f3);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```